# Print Excel Spreadsheet using Template?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, printing, spreadsheet

So Let's say I have a spreadsheet

| No | Name | Class | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jack | Science | Male |
| 2 | Rose | Science | Female |
| 3 | Kevin | Social | Male |
| 4 | Olive | Social | Female |

and I have template

| No | Name | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  |
| 2 |  |  |
| 3 |  |  |
| 4 |  |  |

**How to print automatically (if possible) base on their class? So the first print would be like:**

| No | Name | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jack | Male |
| 2 | Rose | Female |
| 3 |  |  |
| 4 |  |  |

And the second one :

| No | Name | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Kevin | Male |
| 2 | Olive | Female |
| 3 |  |  |
| 4 |  |  |

So it like using template and then print based on a data in this example its class

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The most pragmatic approach would be to have one master table/range one one sheet, then have individual sheets that reference/lookup values by referencing the master sheet.  This way, you can simply select the sheet you want to print and (or select multiple by holding down the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key while clicking the sheets) print by worksheet (as opposed to by workbook, cell selection, or current view).

If for whatever reason your range/table can only hold 5 row entries, you can simply make a second page.  Use the Page Break view to define the boundries of the pages, while keeping the content's structure, layout, and header/footer the same/dynamic.  In the view, solid lines define the print-area's edge, and dotted lines define each page's edge.  In print setup, you can choose to print by *n<sub>X</sub>* by *n<sub>Y</sub>* pages, which will auto-size the contents to best fit the parameters.